# Matching text string on first letter in SQL query

Tags: sql, vb.net

SAMPLE CODE:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM " + tblName + " WHERE needsTranslation = 'True' AND dataText LIKE " & "'" & alpha & "%" & "'" & " ORDER BY dataText;"
da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, strConnection)
```

OP:
I would like to create a SQL query that returns all records when the first letter of a string matches my variable. I am coding this in an ASP.net code behind page in vb.net.

```
SELECT * FROM " + tblName + " WHERE textData = ' & alpha & "
```

In this exmample textData is a string of text and alpha is a single letter a through z or A through Z.

I don't need the criteria to be case sensitive, but I do need only the first letter of textData to match alpha.

I have tested the LIKE comparator and it does not return all records that begin with alpha.

What is the best way to do this? Any and all help will be appreciated.

thanks again,

Comment: Please provide the SQL where LIKE didn't work because that's exactly what should work

Comment: Can you show us your query with `LIKE` that didn't work?

Comment: Can you provide some example strings that the query should match and some examples of what should not match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator is what you'd want to use, but you have to use the `%` wildcard character like so:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE textData LIKE 'a%'
```

Comment: I started to test with the Substring operator I'll switch back to LIKE and update resutls shortly. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Current code updated in OP, returns invalid Column name on the value of alpha variable.

Comment: @marc11h - Note also, that this answer encloses the string in `'` and not `"`.  This is one of the reasons that parameterised queries are recommended, using them you can't make such a mistake.

Comment: This is the fix for the quotes that solved the problem.... " & "'" & alpha & "%" & "'" & " I will update the SAMPLE CODE above to show the syntax more clearly. And I typically have used parameterized queries, just looking for quick test on this. Thanks again, it is working great.

Answer (score 2):

SQL has sub-string operator  SUBSTR() or SUBSTRING()

select * from tableName where substr( textData ) in ( 'A', 'B', 'C', ... );

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add to the comments on one of the other posts, but I'll strongly second the need to use a parameterized query for these reasons (you can include usage of the like operator with the wildcard % like the other answer correctly summarized to answer your question):

1. It will protect you from making mistakes with single quotes, especially if the user enters a search string that includes them
   (they will cause your query to fail).
2. It protects you from SQL injection exploits.  Example, a user were able to input the value of the variable "alpha" in the above
   example they could enter something like:

   '; DELETE FROM ;

   If the user you were using had excessive database rights, they could
   wreak all kinds of havoc (or they could potentially get access to
   data they shouldn't have access to).

Comment: Understood, but in this instance, the only available values of alpha are hard coded, alpha characters.